# Page Specific Configuration in Web.Config

Tags: asp.net, web-config

I do wonder whether there is a way to set page-based configuration in web.config? Lets say I have `Default.aspx` and `Product.aspx` and I want to define different configurations such as `EnableViewState` etc. but in `web.config` rather than in page itself.

So you may ask why? Please do understand this is how it should be.

Comment: Umm you can just set Page.EnableViewState directly within the pages where you want it to be different from most pages... don't need to use web.config for this.

Comment: @Robert Levy: Why U No Read last paragraph?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use the [location](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b6x6shw7.aspx) tag in web.config to specify different settings for different paths.

```
<configuration>
   <location path="Logon.aspx">
      <system.web>
         <authorization>
            <allow users="?"/>
         </authorization>
      </system.web>
   </location>

   <location path="UploadPage.aspx">
     <system.web>
       <httpRuntime maxRequestLength="128"/>
    </system.web>
  </location>
</configuration>
```

Comment: I'd forgotten about this feature. Accept this answer!

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if this is the *only* solution, but placing the page in its own folder and defining a web.config in that folder would allow you to achieve per-page configuration. Combine this with custom routing and it wouldn't be *completely* horrible.

Comment: You are right this is not the only solution. When authorizing specific pages may be differently the <location> tag is the best choice.